# SUPPE-10266 ERROR: Failing on view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, supee-10266

The patch is not installing properly. Here is the error:

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Grid/Renderer/Notice.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 70.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
patching file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
```

As you can see it is failing on:

```
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 70.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml.rej
```

Here is my view.phtml file:
[image]

```
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $this->__('Customer Group:') ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getGroupName()) ?></td>
    </tr>
```

I have checked the file against a mirror copy of the Magento view.phtml and the code is:

```
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $this->__('Customer Group:') ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->getGroupName() ?></td>
    </tr>
```

There is `$this->escapeHtml` missing but even when I remove this (or even use the Magento mirror copy of the view.phtml file) the patch still fails at that point.

Also:

```
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml.rej
```

Is not creating any file like this. Due to permissions? If so what permission should I change?

Comment: The fact that the .rej file can't be written, is due to permissions. You need to execute the .sh script as a user that can write to this folder, or change the folder permissions. Which version of Magento are you using? And do you have all previous patches applied?

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 and yes, all the previous patches are applied. Only Patch SUPPE-10336 needs installing to but I think the SUPPE-10226 needs to go first?

Comment: I've got 1.9.2.4 also, line 70 for me is a closing </tr> tag. Check https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.4/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml

Comment: For me it's the opening tag `<tr>`, could it be that I have a line missing somewhere in the file? I have even used `Magento 1.9.2.4` `view.phtml` mirror file and line 70 was the opening `<tr>` tag.

Comment: Your 1.9.2.4 mirror might not be correct - please try the version from the git link above (goto raw view and copy there), replace entire then re-run patch script. Lines must be exactly as the script wants, as it is running a `diff` command against the files.

Comment: I have done the above, used the file you have given from git. Now the closing `</tr>` tag is on the line 70. Nothing change in the file except the line-break. Still when I run the patch, same error on the same line. However, this time is the closing `</tr>` tag.

Comment: Interesting. All the patch does on that file is add the escapeHtml, which you originally had. You might want to consider https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-10266-without-ssh/

Comment: Yes, it's really weird. So the patch actually worked and have modified the view.phtml file but throws an error? Unless the file already had the `escapeHtml` in there but I doubt that. I will use the method you posted and tell you how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved the issue:

Manually patched the `view.phtml` file and deleted the respective line from the patch script.

Comment: could you pls help me : my error : https://snag.gy/hWXebp.jpg.     create_admin.phtml file : https://justpaste.it/1eawg

Comment: Is the file `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv` in this location? Also I don't understand why did you paste the `create_admin.phtml` file code here...